# Accessing values of dense_vector in elasticsearch possible?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

say i have a document index with a dense_vector field, for example:

```
 "mappings": {
            "_meta": { 
                "imagedir": imgdir
            },
            "properties": {
                "imageid": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "densevec: {
                    "type": "dense_vector",
                    "dims": dim
                }   
            }
```

Is it possible in a script query to access single values of a dense_vector type? For example like indexing an array?

```
"script": {
                                "lang":"painless",
                                "source": """
                                def a = doc['densevec'][0];
                                def b = doc['densevec'][1];
                                return a + b;
                                """,
}
```

Is it also possible to define a new dense_vector inside a script query?
Like:

```
"script": {
                                "lang":"painless",
                                "source": """
                                dense_vector d = new dense_vector(...);
                                """,
}
```

Greetings,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet supported in ES but there's an ongoing discussion on github to [expose dense vectors in painless](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/51964).

As to instantiating new vectors within the script -- you can still use a trivial array of numbers. For instance the `dotProduct` function accepts both `dense_vectors` and arrays as input:

```
"script": {
   "source": """
      double value = dotProduct(params.query_vector, 'my_dense_vector');  
      return sigmoid(1, Math.E, -value); 
   """,
   "params": {
     "query_vector": [4, 3.4, -0.2]
   }
}
```

The currently available (11/2020) vector functions [are listed here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#vector-functions).